# Real root in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

MATLAB code:

```
x^(1/3)
```

If `x = -1` then the result is `0.5000 + 0.8660i`, but I only want the real root `-1`.

How do I modify the above expression?

PS: I don't want such a solution:

```
sign(x)*(abs(x))^(1/3)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `^` produces only one root. From [Mathworks](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/102035-why-does-the-cube-root-of-a-negative-number-give-a-complex-result-in-matlab#answer_111381),

> The root returned by `^` is the one with the **smallest absolute phase** angle returned from the `angle` function. When two values are equal in absolute phase angle, then the `^` operator returns the positive one.

To find the real root use [`nthroot`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nthroot.html):

> `Y = nthroot(X,N)` returns the **real** nth root of the elements of `X`. Both `X` and `N` must be real scalars or arrays of the same size. If an element in `X` is negative, then the corresponding element in `N` must be an odd integer.

Example:

```
>> nthroot(-1, 3)
ans = 
    -1
```

Comment: Your explanation on `^` is helpful.

Answer (score 4):

You will probably have to use [`nthroot`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nthroot.html):

```
>> nthroot(-1, 3)

ans =
    -1
```

Comment: You were 7 seconds faster! :-)

Comment: Thank both of you. @LuisMendo

Comment: @LuisMendo Jedi reflexes :) But your answer is (after the edits) more complete!